# barcodefraglibv2 launches with the fragment as black screen

Tags: android, barcode

I'm experimenting with the zxing barcodefraglibv2. I imported it as a module and after much failure working with it, I started a new project and compiled the sample activity that is provided. I ended up getting the same results with the sample as the one I built around the sample--the app launches but where there should be a camera screen ready to scan, I get a black screen. In my logcat I get this error: An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0, along with the usual data dump.  I'll gladly provide the whole dump if someone needs it.  I've tried running the device on a Nexus 5 and Nexus 7.  Again, this is the code provided with the package, so I don't know what's going on.

Thanks for any help.

MainActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.abhi.barcode.frag.libv2.BarcodeFragment;
import com.abhi.barcode.frag.libv2.IScanResultHandler;
import com.abhi.barcode.frag.libv2.ScanResult;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IScanResultHandler {
BarcodeFragment brf;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FragmentTransaction trx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    brf = new BarcodeFragment();
    trx.add(R.id.testFragmentHolder, brf, "HOLDER");
    trx.commit();
    //brf = (BarcodeFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.barcodeFragment);
    brf.setDecodeFor(MODE.ONE_D_MODE);
    brf.setScanResultHandler(this);
}

@Override
public void scanResult(ScanResult result) {
    Toast.makeText(this, result.getRawResult().getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try{
        brf.restart();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/testFragmentHolder"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.valdes.fuckingbarcode.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="198dp"
    android:text="Scan" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/barcodeFragment"
    android:name="com.abhi.barcode.frag.libv2.BarcodeFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.valdes.barcode">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Don't require camera, as this requires a rear camera. This allows it to work on the Nexus 7 -->
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="false" />
<!-- TODO replace above two with next line after Android 4.2 -->
<!-- <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"/> -->
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  API 23 requires requesting permissions at run time.  Two fixes:

1) Request persmission at run time.  You can read about this here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

2) Compile at API 22.

There are still some issues, but that's the fix to this particular question.